# How do I send an email from C# using data extension and Triggered Send

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, dataextensions, c#, triggered-send

I would like to Trigger an email using data extension. Data extension and Triggered Send is already created in Marketing Cloud UI. How do we trigger the email in C# using SOAP API? Do we need to multiple SOAP API calls or single SOAP API call to Marketing Cloud to trigger the email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a single API call.  The official documentation should get you going in the right direction:

[**Send TriggeredSend Email**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/send_triggeredsend_email.htm)

The Data Extension needs to be created with the Triggered Send Definition template.  It should not have a Primary Key.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But I am looking for how to populate data to data extension. Above link does not have information for Data extension. We should be using only data extension. We should not be using subscriber option. How we can map existing data extention to the triggered send object to trigger the email?

Comment: If the Data Extension is associated with the Trigger Send Definition, then the row will be inserted in the DE automatically before the email is sent.

Comment: Sorry. I am not clear on this. How do we pass dynamic data to DE via Triggered Send. Basically how we can assign data extension to triggered send. The example which you mentioned does not help related data extension.

Comment: When you configure a Triggered Send Definition in the SFMC UI, you can associate a template-based DE with it.  Then in your API call, when you specify attributes that match the column names in the DE, they'll get recorded.